# Android M - runtime permission. Is it possible to get all permissions required for the app in single click?

Tags: android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

requestPermissions(..) ends up giving multiple permission requests where user needs to keep pressing allow or deny button.

Is it possible to get the popup with some check box or so .. 
Or at least single accept or deny for all the permissions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> requestPermissions(..) ends up giving multiple popups where user needs to keep pressing allow or deny button.

Well, it is only one window, but yes, the user has to accept/deny each permission group.

> Is it possible to get a single popup with some check box or so .. Or at least single accept or deny for all the permissions.

Only ask for permissions from one permission group.

Otherwise, no. Bear in mind that this is a system-supplied UI, and so Google may make changes to it in future versions of Android.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, is there any way opened up by google to allow all permission with single user acceptance? It would have been better to give both the choices for app developer...

Comment: @Aun: "But, is there any way opened up by google to allow all permission with single user acceptance?" -- as I wrote, no.